# Rotate a cube on axis

Tags: c#, 3d, rotation, system.drawing

I'm using a paintbox and the System.Drawing functions to do this. Also a self-made class to convert 2D to 3D.

I try to rotate a cube on Y-axis first to then proceed to X and Z.

These are the coordinates:

```
float x1 = 0, y1 = 100, z1 = 0;
float x2 = 100, y2 = 100, z2 = 0;
float x3 = 100, y3 = 0, z3 = 0;
float x4 = 0, y4 = 0, z4 = 0;
float x5 = 0, y5 = 100, z5 = 100;
float x6 = 100, y6 = 100, z6 = 100;
float x7 = 100, y7 = 0, z7 = 100;
float x8 = 0, y8 = 0, z8 = 100;
```

On the picturebox (just to set coordinates in the center of the picturebox):

```
PointF3D[] cubo = {
new PointF3D(x1 + pictureBox1.Width/2, pictureBox1.Height/2 - y1, z1),
new PointF3D(x2 + pictureBox1.Width/2, pictureBox1.Height/2 - y2, z2),
new PointF3D(x3 + pictureBox1.Width/2, pictureBox1.Height/2 - y3, z3),
new PointF3D(x4 + pictureBox1.Width/2, pictureBox1.Height/2 - y4, z4),
new PointF3D(x5 + pictureBox1.Width/2, pictureBox1.Height/2 - y5, z5),
new PointF3D(x6 + pictureBox1.Width/2, pictureBox1.Height/2 - y6, z6),
new PointF3D(x7 + pictureBox1.Width/2, pictureBox1.Height/2 - y7, z7),
new PointF3D(x8 + pictureBox1.Width/2, pictureBox1.Height/2 - y8, z8)
};
```

And the timer to make it an animation:

```
angulo++;

x2 = (float)((z2 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) + (x2 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
z2 = (float)((z2 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) - (x2 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));

x3 = (float)((z3 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) + (x3 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
z3 = (float)((z3 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) - (x3 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));

x5 = (float)((z5 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) + (x5 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
z5 = (float)((z5 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) - (x5 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));

x6 = (float)((z6 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) + (x6 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
z6 = (float)((z6 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) - (x6 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));

x7 = (float)((z7 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) + (x7 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
z7 = (float)((z7 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) - (x7 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));

x8 = (float)((z8 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) + (x8 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
z8 = (float)((z8 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) - (x8 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
```

So, doing a math research I found that formula to rotate on an axis using the rotation matrix and just used it on the code. The cube starts rotating well but at tick 20, more or less, the cube is getting smaller and smaller.
Is there a problem with the code? Or maybe I wrongly aplied the formula? Is there another way to do it? I tried using direction cosines but the cube just deforms.

Comment: why not use matrices

Comment: I don't really know how to aply them on the program, but I found some formulas that are based on the rotation matrices. For example: To rotate around Y-axis (if Y-axis is the vertical one on R3). z' = zCos(theta) -Xsin(theta); x' = zSin(theta) + xCos(theta). But I just can't make it work properly. The cube shrinks as he rotates.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at your formulas:

```
x2 = (float)((z2 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) + (x2 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
z2 = (float)((z2 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) - (x2 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
```

Taken alone, each line is correct. But they don't play well together. The reason for that is that you need `x2` to calculate `z2`. But you already modified `x2` in the previous line. So you need to cache the values:

```
float rotatedX2 = (float)((z2 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) + (x2 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
z2 = (float)((z2 * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) - (x2 * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
x2 = rotatedX2;
```

The same goes for the other points.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
I tried the Nico Schertler idea but the cube deforms, even so, that answer give an idea. I'm overwriting the points over and over again so I just declare a new set of variables to keep the original points, in that way I'm rotating the original figure and not the new figure, that's why it keeps shrinking; I wasn't rotating the original cube but the new ones, over and over again.

```
 x2 = (float)((z2a * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) + (x2a * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
 z2 = (float)((z2a * Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180)) - (x2a * Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180)));
```

z2a and x2a will always keep the original values of the cube for calculations, while x2 and z2 are the new ones for drawing purposes.

Thanks to Nico Schertler for the idea.